# SearchView inside a fragment containing ListView?

Tags: android, arrays, searchview

I am using fragments in my app. Every fragment has a listview. The ListViews are custom listviews containing a single image view.

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_notification_overlay" />
```

The listview items are images. I want to implement searchview. I want to search by name of each listview item eg "jingle bells etc" and also by number i.e "1,2. . . and so on.

My java file containing listview titles is.

```
public class carolFrag extends Fragment {

//code

public carolFrag() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

private static final String TAG = "carolFrag";

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup main_content, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_carol, main_content, false);


    final int[] menuImage = {R.drawable.carol_1_title, R.drawable.carol_2_title,R.drawable.carol_3_title,R.drawable.carol_4_title,R.drawable.carol_5_title,R.drawable.carol_6_title,R.drawable.carol_7_title,R.drawable.carol_8_title,R.drawable.carol_9_title,R.drawable.carol_10_title,R.drawable.carol_11_title};
    final ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.CarolList);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {


            Intent intent1 = new Intent (getActivity(), PackageC.class)  
            intent1.putExtra("position", position);
            startActivity(intent1);




        }
    });
    AdapterCarols adapter = new AdapterCarols(getContext(), menuImage);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment



    return view;
}
```

}

I am unable to make any logic as the array has drawables in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the array is full of drawables, and it's not a database thing or anithing every solution you i'll get will be a work around. The simples, i believe, is to have another array maybe an  - String[] - with the names of the drawables in the same order they are in the original  - final int[] menuImage - you can make the search in the array of String and save the position of the results. Then use those positions to create a new array ( int[] ) putting in this new array the drawables that matches those positions. Finally change the adapter of the list view, passing the array with the results and notifydatachange(); in the listview for it to update visually.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
main_content, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_carol, main_content, false);


final int[] menuImage = {R.drawable.carol_1_title, R.drawable.carol_2_title,R.drawable.carol_3_title,R.drawable.carol_4_title,R.drawable.carol_5_title,R.drawable.carol_6_title,R.drawable.carol_7_title,R.drawable.carol_8_title,R.drawable.carol_9_title,R.drawable.carol_10_title,R.drawable.carol_11_title};


final ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.CarolList);

SearchView sv = view.findviewById(R.id.searchview);
 sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener()
            {
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String par1)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String par1)
                {

                      int [] searchresults = PerformSearch(par1);
                       AdapterCarols newadapter = new 
                               AdapterCarols(getContext(), searchresults);
                       listView.setAdapter(adapter);   
                     listview.invalidate(); // don't remember listview refresh method. I work with Recyclerview, they have a notifyDatasetChange(); method.   

                 }
         });

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {


        Intent intent1 = new Intent (getActivity(), PackageC.class)  
        intent1.putExtra("position", position);
        startActivity(intent1);




    }
});
AdapterCarols adapter = new AdapterCarols(getContext(), menuImage);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

// Inflate the layout for this fragment



return view;
}


private int[] PerformSearch(par1)
{

String [] strcarols = {carol_1_title,carol_2_title,carol_3_title,carol_4_title,carol_5_title,carol_6_title,carol_7_title,carol_8_title,carol_9_title,carol_10_title,carol_11_title};

 int[] menuImage = {R.drawable.carol_1_title, R.drawable.carol_2_title,R.drawable.carol_3_title,R.drawable.carol_4_title,R.drawable.carol_5_title,R.drawable.carol_6_title,R.drawable.carol_7_title,R.drawable.carol_8_title,R.drawable.carol_9_title,R.drawable.carol_10_title,R.drawable.carol_11_title};

int[] results = new int[];

int carolsresultcount = 0, index =0;
   /// simplest way
   for(String carol:strcarols)
   {
     if(carol.contains(par1))
      {
         results [carolsresultcount++] = menuImage [index];
       }
      index++;
   }

return results;


}
```

I hope this can solve your problem.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: Its not working. Can it be done with hashmaps? i don't remember hashmaps.

Comment: It says PerformSearch() in carolFrag cannot be applied. It cannot resolve adapter in listView.setAdapter(adapter);. And it cannot resolve listview in  listview.invalidate();. It cannot resolve titles in String[] strcarols = {titles};

Comment: first: carol_1_title,carol_2_title etc are strings so they should be "carol_1_title" , "carol_2_title"     second what i mean by listview.invalidate(); is that you should order the listview to refresh, some views has an invalidate() method that take care of that, maybe the adapter is the one you should tell invalidate()  o notifyDataChange()  i don't exactly know cause i work with recycler view wich in a future i advice you to learn to work with.